# Условные конструкции Javascript

Tags: javascript

> если пользователь ввел знак плюс то первое и второе значение инпутов должны суммироваться и так с остальными математическими операциями точно также, когда я прописываю иф он не выводит ничего

```js
function go(){
    var x = document.getElementById('test');
    var y = document.getElementById('test2');
    var x1 = Number(x.value);
    var y1 = Number(y.value);
    var math = document.getElementById('znak');
    if(math === '+'){
        var result = x1 + y1
        alert(result)
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" value placeholder="Введите первое число!" id="test">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" value placeholder="Введите второе число!" id="test2">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" value placeholder="Математический знак:" id="znak">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="go()">Нажми на меня!</button>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в условии:

```js
if (math === '+') { // Должно быть (math.value === '+')
  var result = x1 + y1
  alert(result)
}
```

```js
let x = document.getElementById('test');
let y = document.getElementById('test2');
let math = document.getElementById('znak');

function go() {
  let x1 = Number(x.value);
  let y1 = Number(y.value);
  if (math.value === '+') {
    let result = x1 + y1
    alert(result)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="text" value placeholder="Введите первое число!" id="test">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" value placeholder="Введите второе число!" id="test2">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" value placeholder="Математический знак:" id="znak">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="go()">Нажми на меня!</button>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```